# Swap shift-enter and enter in python interactive window VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, configuration

In the interactive window in vscode you press shift-enter to run the code you just typed and enter to go to the next line. Can I swap this?
[image]

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: @DerekEden unfortunately no.

Comment: lol, this is the only reason I don't use interactive window.....I tried changing the keyboard shortcut but it wouldnt let me use Enter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current answers explain how to make "enter" execute the command but they don't give you the other half: make shift+enter insert a new line. Here is the complete solution (I aggregated multiple solutions from various answers to similar questions to credit to everyone else who helped). Bonus: I come from MATLAB so I also made "F9" execute selection in the ipython window.

Open keybindings.json (ctrl+shift+p, open keyboard shortcuts (JSON)
Add the following:

```
    [
    {
        "key": "enter",
        "command": "interactive.execute",
        "when": "!suggestWidgetVisible && resourceScheme == 'vscode-interactive'"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+enter",
        "command": "",
        "when": "!suggestWidgetVisible && resourceScheme == 'vscode-interactive'"
    },
    {
        "key": "f9",
        "command": "jupyter.execSelectionInteractive",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocussed && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"
    }
]
```

Comment: I needed `"when": "!suggestWidgetVisible && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.interactive'"`. **`resourceScheme`** did not work for me

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I think an update broke my solution at some point and yes, your solution is the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this finally by editing the "keybindings.json" file. If you click the "Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" button at the top right of the "Keyboard Shortcuts" window, it will open this file, and then you can edit/add it yourself. For example, it may look like this... the last item is the new one that does the trick for this specific shortcut:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaultsauto[]
[
    {
        "key": "f9",
        "command": "-editor.debug.action.toggleBreakpoint",
        "when": "debuggersAvailable && editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "f9",
        "command": "jupyter.execSelectionInteractive",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !findInputFocussed && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocussed && editorLangId == 'python'"
    },
    {
        "key": "enter",
        "command": "jupyter.execSelectionInteractive",
        "when": "resourceScheme == 'vscode-interactive'"
    },
]
```

It took me a bit of trial and error to make it so that "enter" caused the interactive cell to run, but did not also cause the editor to "run" every time I hit "enter" within it.

Answer (score 1):

I better version that cleans the code block is :

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[{
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "interactive.execute",
    "when": "!suggestWidgetVisible && resourceScheme == 'vscode-interactive'"
},
]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the best answer, it not only sends your code to the interactive window but also clears the console for your next command

Comment: @JeffBezos Appreciate it:) When do I start at Amazon